# Structure of Hilbert Space in Bosonic String Theory

Tags: string-theory, spacetime-dimensions, quantization

My question is about the canonical quantization of free bosonic string theory as described by Green, Schwarz & Witten. There they use spurious states to calculate a value for the ambiguity parameter $a$ of the Virasoro Generator $L_0$ and the dimension $D$ of the Spacetime. They argue as follows:

Since there is a regime of values of $a,D$ where the physical Hilbert Space has negative norm states and there has to be a regime of these values where the Hilbertspace is positive definite there will be a border between these two regimes on which we can find an increase in the number of zero normed states.

So my question is: How can we know that the Hilbertspace really has such a simple structure? Couldn't there be various borders which then meant that the regime for which the physical Hilbertspace really is physical is not simply connected?